# Notice: Undefined offset while assigning explode to a list

Tags: php, string, explode

I am trying to get a values from comma separated list for that I have used `explode()` method, but it will works for only in some cases only in other cases it's giving notice like:

> Notice: Undefined offset

My code:

case 1 (working properlly):

```
$permission = 1,2,3,4,5 ; // this is fetching values from database 

list($p1, $p2,$p3,$p4,$p5) = explode(',', $permission);
echo $p1. "</BR>".$p2. "</BR>".$p3. "</BR>".$p4. "</BR>".$p5 ;
```

output:

```
1 2 3 4 5
```

case 2 (Notice: Undefined offset: 4  and Notice: Undefined offset: 3):

```
$permission = 1,2,3 ;// this is fetching values from database

list($p1, $p2,$p3,$p4,$p5) = explode(',', $permission);
echo $p1. "</BR>".$p2. "</BR>".$p3. "</BR>".$p4. "</BR>".$p5 ;
```

output:

```
1 2 3 with (Notice: Undefined offset: 4  and Notice: Undefined offset: 3)
```

How to overcome this notice. Or my method itself is wrong.

Any other good way?

Comment: `list($p1, $p2,$p3,$p4,$p5) = explode(',', $permission . ',,,,');`

Comment: @MarkBaker I think this is a really bad solution!

Comment: It's not a good solution when you're playing with several values (like 5); when you're playing with a possible 1 or 2, then it has it's uses

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because it can't save a value in each variable in your list, since your string only has 2 commas == 3 values.

So to solve this simply save it in an array and loop over the array, like this:

```
$arr = explode(',', $permission);

foreach($arr as $v)
    echo $v . "<br>";
```

Answer (score 0):

In your second example, you only have three values being returned from the database- yet you are trying to set 5